# XSLT group duplicate elements of a node and pass as a request

Tags: xslt

I am getting multiple ReplyDTO nodes and duplicate estimateNo fields.
Requirement is , we have to find whether we are getting any duplicate estimateNo and if we are getting any duplicate estimateNo , then check the creationDate and creationTime of that particular node "ReplyDTO " and get the latest estimate number .

How to get estimate numbers here using xslt?

Sample payload:

```
<replyelement xmlns:ns1="http://some.url">
    <ns1:ReplyDTO>                               
        <ns1:creationDate>20160404</ns1:creationDate>
        <ns1:creationTime>094843</ns1:creationTime>
        <ns1:estimateNo>1234</ns1:estimateNo>
        <ns1:versionNo>006</ns1:versionNo>
    </ns1:ReplyDTO>    
    <ns1:ReplyDTO>                       
        <ns1:creationDate>20160404</ns1:creationDate>
        <ns1:creationTime>094844</ns1:creationTime>
        <ns1:estimateNo>5678</ns1:estimateNo>
        <ns1:versionNo>006</ns1:versionNo>
    </ns1:ReplyDTO>    
    <ns1:ReplyDTO>                        
        <ns1:creationDate>20160404</ns1:creationDate>
        <ns1:creationTime>094843</ns1:creationTime>
        <ns1:estimateNo>5678</ns1:estimateNo>        
        <ns1:versionNo>006</ns1:versionNo>
    </ns1:ReplyDTO>
    <ns1:ReplyDTO>
        <ns1:creationDate>20160404</ns1:creationDate>
        <ns1:creationTime>094843</ns1:creationTime>
        <ns1:estimateNo>1234</ns1:estimateNo>        
        <ns1:versionNo>006</ns1:versionNo>
    </ns1:ReplyDTO>
</replyelement>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT-2.0 template copies the newest of each `ns1:estimateNo` elements. Unfortunately your example is not a very good one, because all the `ns1:ReplyDTO` have the same `ns1:creationDate`. So if the date is the same, it chooses based on `ns1:creationTime`, with the greatest number first. This is achieved with the two `xsl:sort`s in the `perform-sort`. The `current-group()` selects all the distinct `ns1:estimateNo` elements from which it chooses - after sorting - the first one with `$estimates/*[1]`.

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:replyelement>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="ns1:ReplyDTO" group-by="ns1:estimateNo">
    <xsl:variable name="estimates">
      <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
        <xsl:sort select="ns1:creationDate" order="descending" />
        <xsl:sort select="ns1:creationTime" order="descending" />
      </xsl:perform-sort> 
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$estimates/*[1]" />  
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
<ns1:ReplyDTO>
    <ns1:creationDate>20160404</ns1:creationDate>
    <ns1:creationTime>194843</ns1:creationTime>
    <ns1:estimateNo>1234</ns1:estimateNo>
    <ns1:versionNo>006</ns1:versionNo>
</ns1:ReplyDTO>
<ns1:ReplyDTO>                       
    <ns1:creationDate>20160404</ns1:creationDate>
    <ns1:creationTime>094844</ns1:creationTime>
    <ns1:estimateNo>5678</ns1:estimateNo>        
    <ns1:versionNo>006</ns1:versionNo>
</ns1:ReplyDTO>
```

Make sure that the namespace `ns1` is defined in both the XML and the XSLT.

Comment: Hi , If creationdate is different , then also is this work ,

Comment: <ns1:ReplyDTO xmlns:ns1="http://some.url">                               
    <ns1:creationDate>20160404</ns1:creationDate>
    <ns1:creationTime>094843</ns1:creationTime>
    <ns1:estimateNo>1234</ns1:estimateNo>                              
    <ns1:versionNo>006</ns1:versionNo>
</ns1:ReplyDTO>
<ns1:ReplyDTO xmlns:ns1="http://some.url">                       
    <ns1:creationDate>20160403</ns1:creationDate>
    <ns1:creationTime>094844</ns1:creationTime>
    <ns1:estimateNo>1234</ns1:estimateNo>                                
    <ns1:versionNo>006</ns1:versionNo>
<:ReplyDTO>

Comment: Hi , Sorry I forgot to inform that if creation date is same , then we have to look for creationtime field , now could you explain me how can we add creationtime logic above

Comment: Hi thanks,  the variable part is not working properly. It is not giving any result for <xsl:copy-of select="$estimates/*[1]" />, I have replaced this with <xsl:copy-of select="." />  , then I am getting result but not the accurate one. It is displaying the data of just first node,  not checking greater date value,  please help

Comment: If that's not working, the rest probably isn't, too. Did you replace the `/root` of the template with the actual name and set the namespaces properly?

Comment: In the place of /root I am giving just /

Comment: Try `$estimates/*` to check if there's any data at all.

Comment: The `ns1:ReplyDTO` elements have to be wrapped in another node. Otherwise it would be invalid XML. So replacing it with `/` probably won't work.

Comment: Giving empty result

Comment: What's the output if you put `<xsl:value-of select="name()" />` immediately before `<xsl:for-each-group...`. That should be the element name of the wrapping node of the `ns1:ReplyDTO` elements.

Comment: The root element is retrieveres,  under that out, and under that replyelement.  Under this we have ReplyDTO.  So I already wrapped it with parent elements.

Comment: Good. Then use `<xsl:template match="replyelement">` as the first line. Sorry. First try was wrong.

Comment: No luck,  empty result.  If I give match ="/"  , it is giving result.  But it is giving estimate creation date data of first node.  Ex.  Suppose estimateno is 1234 and it repeated twice,  then it is giving data of just first node,  it is not sorting

Comment: I edited your XML sample in the question. With that and `<xsl:template match="replyelement">` it does work here (you probably must adjust the namespace).

Comment: I have added as you said,  same result is coming.  The results is coming like : if same estimate number is coming 2 times,  then our xslt returning second node value.  I suggest you change date values,  like for first node give any latest date and second estimate give any old date,  you will get result of second node.

Comment: That's the problem if the question doesn't have a [mcve]. I'm sorry, but it looks like I can't help you.